# setup github bot to report security vulnerabilities for all repos i have access to

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am trying to setup a security scanner/bot in github. Its main responsibility is to scan all files to see if there is any secrets typed in frree text instead of using git secrets.
I want to do it in following levels:

1. All Repositories that i have access to
2. All Repositories my organization has created so far

Answer (score 1):

Under your GitHub settings there is a category for Security. In there, you can find an enable-all button to enable Dependabot and code- and secret scanning for all repositories on your own profile.

Under the organisation setting, if you are an organization admin, you can do the same thing for all repos in an organization.

These is no UI to enable these features on all repos you have access to from other users. Or to enable it in all repositories in all repositories from organizations you're not an admin of.

I think there's an API you can leverage to enable these features.

For then non-built-in security features you can leverage required workflows to enable a GitHub actions workflow across all repositories in your organization.

And you can publish a GitHub App and enable that on all repositories you have access to and then leverage the API to perform the scanning using the token it receives to access all the repos.